# Dummy/fake job appears when searching job listings

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

I kinda feel this job offer shouldn't be in the public website or out of a sandbox: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/84937/test-gwe2

Are test insertions allowed to appear in the public careers website?

To reproduce the issue I just checked "Allows Remote" in the search box and pressed "Search"

[image]

Comment: Question is, how did you find it? Is it linked from somewhere?

Comment: @ShadowWizard by only checking "Allows remote" and just pressing "Search" on the careers website. At the time of writing this it's the second result for me.

Comment: Well, this is obviously a bug, those things should not be in production. (meaning as search results - having direct URL is fine)

Comment: I can't find it anymore. It might have been fixed.

Comment: It seems to have gone from search... probably been fixed

Comment: lol, they're quick! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The listing has been expired so that it doesn't appear in searches anymore.

A customer had mistakenly posted a test listing from the API, we'll get in touch with them.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: *Bring the smiting stick!* :-D

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for being that reactive!